# "By the time ...", does this need a comma afterwards?

Tags: commas

I came across this sentence in a book:

*"By the time he died Faraday had helped to create..."*

Don't you think you should put a comma after "died"?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally write it out as:
"By the time he died, Faraday had helped to create..."
simply because it changes the subject into another person mid-sentence, and it would make a lot more sense to separate it with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is perfectly acceptable with or without a comma. Whether to use one is simply a matter of style.

Say the sentence out loud. Do you pause? If you're addressing the Royal Society you probably do. You're in a formal situation, with a captive audience. You want the full dramatic effect.

But if you're in the pub, defending your scientific hero against someone who believes he achieved nothing, you'll naturally want your speech to flow much more quickly.